# Gitolite mirroring on SVN server

Tags: git, svn, gitolite

I have a git server with gitolite3, but I also need to mirror my repos on SVN server. Is there any way to do it with post-receive hook or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a similar idea in [`miracle2k/gitolite-simple-mirror`](https://github.com/miracle2k/gitolite-simple-mirror), using a gitolite-compatible post-receive hook.

Since it is for mirroring a git repo in GitHub (and not SVN), you can use instead (still in that same post-receive hook) commands from "[Maintaining a Read-Only svn Mirror of a git Repository](http://www.kerrybuckley.org/2009/10/06/maintaining-a-read-only-svn-mirror-of-a-git-repository/)".